# Batch script help required

Tags: batch, shell-script

I have created a batch script which restarts an executable, I am trying to get it to output to a log file showing any errors.

My Script is

```
@echo on

timeout /t 03

set logfile=c:\users\administrator\desktop\C4W\Logs\status.log
echo starting system.exe at %date% %time% >> %logfile%
"./system.exe" -connection "sql instance" -model "model number" -username "admin" -password "" -id 2  >> %logfile%

Pause

Exit 0
```

As you can see my executable is connecting to a sql instance and a model within the sql database. when I run the batch file I get an error on screen saying “The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters”. But my log file does not show this error it just shows that my executable has run with date and time displayed. I have tried putting the & symbol in >>& %logfile% but then I don't see the error message in the cmd window and my log doesn't show it either.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you really using a forward-slash before system.exe?

Comment: my executable isn't called system but it resides on the root level so yes

Comment: Is this Windows? What happens if you change it to a back-slash? Btw ".\" means current directory, whereas "\" is the root directory.

Comment: it is actually to be run on server 2012 r2 changing to a back slash has no effect, I have also tried changing it to c:\system.exe I still get the error message but only in the cmd window and not in my log file

Comment: Try running the command from a prompt as follows: `command 1>nul 2>con`. Does the error get output to the console?

Comment: I have added suggestion and it hasn't had any effect as far as I can see, the error shows on the console with those commands inserted or removed. one thing I didn't put in my original question was that above the error I get !! use -h option for batch usage !! then it sais start connection to the repository... so I think my error message is because it is failing to connect to the sql server

Comment: I noticed I had omitted the password from my script so have added " " as there is no password set, I now have a new error message "The given key was not present in the dictionary." still this error does not show in the log file though

Comment: Is your question "how do I get the error output into my log", or "how do I eliminate this error"?  Please [edit] your question to clarify which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect the command's error output to your logfile, along with any standard output, append `>>logfile.txt 2>>&1` to your command, like this:

```
yourcommand.exe >>logfile.txt 2>>&1
```

The `2>>&1` syntax is necessary to "combine" the StdOut and SteErr streams for redirection into the log file.

#### More Information

- [Redirecting Error Messages from Command Prompt: STDERR/STDOUT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout)

Comment: I have appended my script but still the error does not show in my log file

Comment: What is the exact command you're using right now?

Comment: c:\system.exe -connection "sdsql2012" -model c812ocex -username "admin" -password "" -id 2 command >> %logfile% 2>>&1

Comment: Try replacing `%logfile%` with `log.txt`. Also I assume the missing double-quote before `c:\system.exe` is accidental.

Comment: yes it was accidental, its not a broken name so I completely removed it, tried changing to log.txt still error does not display in log file

Comment: Then I'm afraid this isn't possible with a batch script. These are the only two output streams exposed to console applications. Perhaps running the command through PowerShell would give you more options.

Comment: My instinct would be to use `... >>%logfile% 2>&1` (single `>` on the StdErr redirection), but I can't easily test whether this would make any difference.